# Method That Calculates Slope In Python

Tags: python, object, methods, equation

I'm trying to learn Object Oriented Programming in Python. To do this I need to create a method that calculates the slope of a line, which joins the origin to a point. (I think) we're assuming that the origin is (0,0). For example:

```
Point(4, 10).slopeFromOrigin()
2.5
Point(12, -3).slopeFromOrigin()
-0.25
Point(-6, 0).slopeFromOrigin()
0
```

And we're using the equation `slope = (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1)` to calculate the slope. Also, since dividing by 0 isn't allowed, we need to return `None` when the method fails. Here's what I tried:

```
class Point:

#Point class for representing and manipulating x,y coordinates

    def __init__(self, initX, initY):

#Create a new point at the given coordinates

        self.x = initX
        self.y = initY

    def getX(self):
        return self.x

    def getY(self):
        return self.y

    def distanceFromOrigin(self):
        return ((self.x ** 2) + (self.y ** 2)) ** 0.5

#define a method called slopeFromOrigin here

    def slopeFromOrigin(self):

#set origin values for x and y (0,0)

        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

#slope = (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1)

        if (Point(x) - self.x) == 0:

            return None

        else: 

            return (Point(y) - self.y) / (Point(x) - self.x) 

#some tests to check our code

from test import testEqual
testEqual( Point(4, 10).slopeFromOrigin(), 2.5 )
testEqual( Point(5, 10).slopeFromOrigin(), 2 )
testEqual( Point(0, 10).slopeFromOrigin(), None )
testEqual( Point(20, 10).slopeFromOrigin(), 0.5 )
testEqual( Point(20, 20).slopeFromOrigin(), 1 )
testEqual( Point(4, -10).slopeFromOrigin(), -2.5 )
testEqual( Point(-4, -10).slopeFromOrigin(), 2.5 )
testEqual( Point(-6, 0).slopeFromOrigin(), 0 )
```

As you can see, I'm trying to say that we need the first parameter of Point to be x2, and the second parameter of Point to be y2. I tried it this way and got

`NameError: name 'y' is not defined on line 32`.

I also tried to get the index values of Point like this:

`return (Point[0] - self.y / (Point[1] - self.x)`

But that also gave me an error message:

`TypeError: 'Point' does not support indexing on line 32`

I'm not sure how to get the value of the x and y parameters from `Point` so that the method works when it's tested. Please share your suggestions if you have any. Thank you.

Comment: Returning `None` when the call fails isn't a good idea. Why not let the error just happen?

Comment: Why are you setting `self.x` and `self.y` to 0 in your method? That doesn't make any sense. Think of what that means.

Comment: @Blender this is clearly an assignment. Using getters and setters isn't a good idea either.

Comment: @Blender I don't disagree with you, but like juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out, this is for an assignment.

Comment: In other words, `self` is the point. You want the distance of self from the origin, but you are setting `self` to have the same coordinates as the origin.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh okay yeah that's not what I was going for - was just trying to set the origin as (0,0). After getting rid of those, I'm just left with a ParseError, bad input for the line return = (Point(y) - self.y) / (Point(x) - self.x)

Comment: I wasn't saying that was your only problem, but if you understand *why* that's wrong the solution should be straightforward.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, after cricket_007 said that self.y and self.x _are_ the values for rise over run, the solution made sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First problem

```
self.x = 0
self.y = 0
```

You just set the current point to the origin. Don't do that. The distance from the origin would then be 0...

Second problem `Point(x)` and `Point(y)` are not how you get the values for `self.x` and `self.y`.

Then, slope is simply "rise over run". Plus you want to return `None` when `self.x == 0`.

So, simply

```
def slopeFromOrigin(self):
    if self.x == 0:
        return None
    return self.y / self.x
```

Or even

```
def slopeFromOrigin(self):
    return None if self.x == 0 else self.y / self.x
```

Or let Python return None on its own

```
def slopeFromOrigin(self):
    if self.x != 0:
        return self.y / self.x
```

---

I think your confusion lies in that you think you need to somehow define "the origin". If you needed to do that, you would instead have this

```
origin = Point(0,0)
Point(-6, 0).slopeFromPoint(origin)
```

Comment: Much simpler than I expected. Thanks for the help / explanation.

Comment: Could you please explain how self.y and self.x represent rise and run?

Comment: You move `self.y` steps to "rise" (move up/down), and move `self.x` steps to "run" (move right/left). Negative/positive picks the direction.

Comment: I see. So since the origin is (0,0) we don't even need to do (y2 - y1) to get the rise and (x2 - x1) to get the run when we do rise / run.

Comment: Basically, something like this. `(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)` = `(y2 - 0) / (x2 - 0)` = `(y2) / (x2)`

Answer (score 2):

```
        if (Point(x) - self.x) == 0:

        return None

    else: 

        return (Point(y) - self.y) / (Point(x) - self.x)
```

> As you can see, I'm trying to say that we need the first parameter of Point to be x2, and the second parameter of Point to be y2. I tried it this way and got
>
> NameError: name 'y' is not defined on line 32.

You're trying to access the value of `y`, which is a global variable that you haven't assigned yet.

> I also tried to get the index values of Point like this:
>
> return (Point[0] - self.y / (Point[1] - self.x)

Two problems:

1. "Point" is a class, not an object (which is an instance of an object).
2. Even if you've put an object instead, Point is not an list-like object. In order to access an item using index like `variableName[index]`, the class of the `variableName` must have an implementation for [`__getitem__(self, key)`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__). For example:

   ```
   >>> class GoodListClass:
   ...     def __init__(self, list):
   ...         self.myList = list
   ...     def __getitem__(self, key):
   ...         return self.myList[key]
   ...
   >>> class BadListClass:
   ...     def __init__(self, list):
   ...         self.myList = list
   ...
   >>> someList = range(10)
   >>> goodListObject = GoodListClass(someList)
   >>> badListObject = BadListClass(someList)
   >>> print(goodListObject[2])
   2
   >>> print(badListObject[2])
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   AttributeError: BadListClass instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
   ```

Comment: Your second explanation makes sense - why do self.y and self.x automatically represent (y2 - y1) and (x2 - x1)?

Comment: They shouldn't be (at least for your implementation). Can you explain how you came up with that thought?

Comment: Based on the answer given by cricket_007, we have return None if self.x == 0 else self.y / self.x and it works. He simply used self.y / self.x to get the slope, right?

Comment: Ah, that's because you're getting a slope between your point and the origin. So, (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) is equal to y2 / x2, since the point of origin has coordinate of (0,0)